# Is there any online link available to read all 4 vedas?

Tags: vedas

I am very keen to find online books which contain all full 4 vedas.

I have search online but not able to find any good reference.

It will be great help if anyone refer me such link.

Comment: Which is the language do you want to read Vedas in?

Comment: This is the best - https://vedicscriptures.in/rigveda/10/129/2

Comment: Why was the question closed? The OP asked link specifically for Veda, so the other two questions aren't the same. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 0):

You can now read Vedas, Brahmanas, Aranyakas, Upanishads and Vedangas online, started by Govt of India.

Link: vedicheritage.gov.in